# Insert INTEGER/NUMERIC into sqlite but turning to BLOB

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing SQL with python and sqlite.

I have a python list called supermarket_ids and each element of the list is a number: 2.

I also have a column in a sqlite table which stores INTEGER or NUMERIC. I use a for loop to loop the list and insert to sqlite database.

I INSERT the variable to the column, but when I SELECT it from the table, it returns b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' instead of 2.

I tried to alter the column to store either INTEGER or NUMERIC but it is still the same.

My code for INSERT is as follows:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO SKU_Table (Supermarket_ID) VALUES (?)", (supermarket_ids[i]))
```

And when I view it with a database software called DB Browser for SQLite, it shows that the Supermarket_ID is now a BLOB.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Show the code that inserts the value.

Comment: I have already showed the code, is there anymore I need to show?

Comment: Show the code that creates the `supermarket_ids` items.

Comment: This happens, if you use numpy/pandas-types. Convert to `int(v)` before inserting, then it works.

Comment: I think this could be duplicate of the question in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456158/integer-in-python-pandas-becomes-blob-binary-in-sqlite.