# Integer in python/pandas becomes BLOB (binary) in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Storing an integer in sqlite results in BLOBs (binary values) instead of INTEGER in sqlite. The problem is the INT in the "Baujahr" column. The table is created.

```
CREATE TABLE "Objekt" ( `No` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, `Objekt_id` INTEGER, 
`Strecke` TEXT, `Baujahr` INTEGER, `Eigentümer` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`No`) )
```

dataframe and dtypes:

```
id  Strecke  Baujahr Eigentümer Objekt_id
5     A23     1938    Fronz      0327

Objekt.dtypes
Strecke       object
Baujahr        int64
Eigentümer    object
Objekt_id     object
dtype: object
```

The DataFrame ist written to sqlite

```
stmt ="INSERT INTO Objekt (Objekt_id, Strecke, Baujahr, Eigentümer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
c.execute(stmt, (Objekt.Objekt_id.values[0], Objekt.Strecke.values[0], 
Objekt.Baujahr.values[0], Objekt.Eigentümer.values[0] ))
conn.commit()
```

Sqlite works only up to  INT 8 and works not with INT 32 or INT64 (The definition BIGINT in the CREATE TABLE .... does not help either). So I tried to convert using these conversions

```
Objekt.Baujahr.astype(int)
Objekt.Baujahr.astype(np.int8)
Objekt.Baujahr = int(Objekt.Baujahr)
```

The dtypes command shows that Baujahr remained int64!!

I cannot edit the values in the database and by querying these values i get a binary back. Any idea?

Python 3.6.4, sqlite3 2.6.0, pandas 0.22.0

Answer (score 21):

For some reason Sqlite does not accept INT larger than 8 byte. Therefore it is necessary to add the following statements.

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int64, lambda val: int(val))
sqlite3.register_adapter(np.int32, lambda val: int(val))
```

The docs in sqlite are at this point a little bit short. But it works perfectly.

Comment: Very good solution, much better than manually casting the values before insert. Btw: instead of `lambda val: int(val)` you can just use `int`.

Comment: what to do if the data in the database is already a binary blob instead of an integer?

Comment: That was extremely useful. Thanks @Stivi B!!